# "walks" or "walked" or "will walk"?

Tags: tense, verbs, verb-forms

Can anyone explain me the difference between "walks," "walked," and "will walk"?

Example:

> Martha loves exercising so she **walks/walked/will walk** everywhere she goes.

Comment: ... and your work is? You're not learning a thing if we do this for you!

Comment: I need the explanation how this questions works. I can say that im bad in this grammar. Or similar qestions, this is examples.

Answer (score 2):

Those are three different tenses.

> **walks** (third person singular present tense; regular action or habit)
> — *She **walks** everyday.*
>
> **walked** (past tense; completed action on a specific time)
> — *She **walked** yesterday.*
>
> **will walk** (future tense; planned stuff to do in the future)
> — *She **will walk** within two days.*

Comment: @Usernew, I like the style of my given answer, being in the whole quote. Thanks for the edit but I prefer my style.

Comment: A consideration about the format as a "whole quote" is that it makes one wonder if you are simply copying and pasting from another source. If so, it is standard and best practice to link to the source. If not, it gives the impression that you are.

Answer (score 1):

*walks* - present simple tense (3rd person singular)

*will walk* - used to refer to future time (often called the future tense)

*walked* - past simple tense (it's not grammatical in your sentence, since *Martha loves exercising* is in the present tense.)

For more information, I highly suggest you read a basic grammar site about verb tenses. You can start [here on this page](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verb-tenses.htm) at the English Club.